# Markdown rendering with React Components inside at build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, markdown

I have a very specific issue with Preact/React:
I have a `.md` file with some text, which uses react-router's `<Link>` tags inside for navigation. Like this:

```
## Heading
<Link to="/test">Let's go here</Link>
```

In my Component file, I render the Markdown and import the Link Component and pass the Link-components down, using the `preact-markup` component:

```
...
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import text from './text.md';
import Markup from 'preact-markup';

export default class Comp extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Markup markup={text} components={{Link, HashLink}} />;
  }
}
```

For importing the markdown, I use the `@nuxtjs/markdown-it`-loader, which works fine. It all works as expected, but doesn't feel clean.
I would like to be able to either import the Link components inside the markdown file, which would save me some boilerplate code for every view.
Or, even better, I would like to be able to write my markdown inside the Component itself, with the appropriate imports, and compile it all to HTML at build time.
I **don't** like runtime components since they need downloading and parse- and render time.